# Write a Spring Web Socket project without SpringBoot or Maven/Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-websocket

How to create a **Spring Java Web socket** project **with XML or Java Config** but without **Spring Boot**. Where can I find a step-by-step tutorial. I dont know how to use spring boot in ecliplse. Also I dont want to use gradle or maven. I did not find a tutorial to use spring boot in eclipse. As I am new to spring I am unable to start a project without maven or gradle. I need to learn how to create a spring project without any built tool provided I need to use Eclipse. This is purly for learning puropse.

Below is the classes I used to replace Spring boot related main class

**AppConfig Class**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("hello")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class AppConfig  {



}
```

**WebAppInitializer Class**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;  
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;  
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{// extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException 
        {
            try
            {
                 AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();  
                    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);  
                    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);    
                    Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx)); 

                   dynamic.addMapping("/");
                   // dynamic.addMapping("/springStomp/");
                    dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
                    //dynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
                    //ctx.refresh();
                    System.out.println("config done");

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("error");
            }
       }
}
```

**WebSocketConfig Class**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        System.out.println("inside websocket config class");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Remaining is same as in [spring web socket tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)

Comment: Trust me you want to use maven or gradle. You don't want to spend hours searching the internet for all needed and correct dependencies. It will save you tons of time. For starters check the spring reference guide.

Comment: I am in a school closed network. so here I am unable to use maven as it is downloading and our network firwall blocks it.

Comment: So then how do you expect to download the needed jars/zips yourself if that is prohibited by the firewall? If maven cannot download you cannot download.

Comment: Here the admin will download all the jars we needed. So as of now I have almost all jars I needed for [Spring web socket tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/). Now I am stuck with this spring Boot. Can you please tell me how to code without spring boot please.

Comment: @SathishKumarkk Although it's probably not feasable in the short term, you need to get your admin to setup a local repository for the school. Check out http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ and http://www.jfrog.com/open-source/#os-arti

Comment: I have added code in the question. But my application is not running and I did't get any error in console. I only get 404 on browser.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @VibhorBhardwaj Sorry I could not achieve it. If you have the answer please share it as an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I know how that feels, my company network is unfriendly towards my maven calls to download dependencies. If you had to do things the hard way like me goto www.mvnrepository.com and just type spring in the search and you can download the jars you need. If you encounter any NoClassDef errors during deployment or compilation it usually tells you what you are missing, then search for the keywords again in the link.

Comment: +1.  While it makes it *much* easier, Maven isn't *essential* for building a Spring project.  From the top of my head, the spring packages you'll need are: spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-aop, spring-expression, spring-web, spring-websocket.  You'll probably also want spring-webmvc and spring-context-support, and for most real-world applications spring-security, spring-security-core and spring-security-web. There are a handful of transitive dependencies: you'll need a logging framework (I have slf4j-api, slf4j-log4j and log4j in my current project), ...

Comment: aopalliance-1.0.jar for Spring's aspect-oriented features, and Jackson for JSON production (jackson-databind, jackson-annotations and jackson-core).

Answer (score -1):

Just:

1. add gradle plugin in eclipse
2. import following project from spring site as gradle project
3. ???
4. Profit!

Than if you don't want use spring boot remove any spring boot dependincies, add regular deps like spring-context, spring-webmvc, etc. And finally add spring-websocket and spring-messaging libraries.

Comment: your answer does't make any sense to this context.